# Extracting repetition index from apply / map loop

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I'm trying wherever possible to replace my for loops with apply / map functions

However I am stuck when it comes to times where I need to use the loop index as a position. This is easy to do with a `for` loop

Take the following code, I use the index `i` in both the left hand and the right hand side of the assignment:

```
score <- function(x) {

  n <- length(x)
  right <- x

  for(i in 1:n) {
    right[i] <- (n - x[i] + 1) / (i * n)
  }

  (1 / n) * sum(right)
}

score(c(2,1,3))
```

how do i rewrite the above using `map` or `apply` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
x = c(2,1,3)
n = length(x)
(1/n) * sum(sapply(1:n, function(i) (n - x[i] + 1)/(i*n)  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could vectorize this

```
v1 <- c(2, 1, 3)
n <- length(v1)
(1/n) *sum((n - v1 + 1)/(seq_along(v1) * n))
#[1] 0.4259259
```